# Where does the code for a new slot created using QT designer go?

Tags: qt-designer

I am a total newbie to QT.

I am working with qt 4.7.1 on visual studio 2008.

I am trying to implement a button which is all covered by image, and when pressed, the image changes. (image-button)
I am trying to use QT designer to put the button in currect layout then programmatically handle the pressed event (..signal..) to change the icon on the button.

create new mainWindow. put a tool button in it. 
switch to slots&signals mode. created a signal-slot from the button pressed() to new slot1() on the window.
now where do I put the code of slot1()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry for my english. It is rly bad, but I'll try to help you.

You have to use inheritance approach. So:
• you created a form, added a connection with slot1() on that form.
• include your form in project, compile it. A file named ui_FormName.h will be generated. At the bottom of that file you will find code like:
`namespace Ui {

class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};

} // namespace Ui`

You have to:
1) Create a new class, inherit from class QMainWindow.
2) In header include generated h-file, add a member of type Ui::MainWindow,  which is declared in that generated .h-file (e.g.: `Ui::MainWindow* m_puiTmp;` ).
3) Also add code:
`public slots: // or private slots:, or protected slots: ... Whatever.

void slot1();`

then create implementation for functions in your new class. Don't forget to add
`m_puiTmp->setupUi( this );` in your constructor, and then create implementation for your `slot1()` slot.

You can also describe your slots and signals in derived class, and then connect them with signals and slots in QtDesigner. Simply when you adding a now slot or signal in designer, rename them in accordance with names, that you set in code.

Hope this will help you. If you can't solve your problem, write me a message. I'll try to help.

Comment: the thing that REALLY CONFUSED is that the designer does not show the slots that YOU defined. if you define a slot 'mySlot' you must manually add it to the list in designer's 'slots and signal mode'.

Comment: it is true. Stupid little bit, but it is hard to implement it